# WebDriver wait duration? How do I know how far I am in it?

Tags: python, selenium

I have my program wait several minutes to find a element. Once it hits, say 1 minute, id like the program to notify me so I can check it out.

Is there anything I can print directly from WebDriverWait? Or will I have to make my own separate timer?

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10000).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@aria-label=%r]" % l))).click()
```

Comment: WebDriverWait is really just a pre-configured FluentWait... you would have to dig into the source code a bit: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.java  Might be easier just to make a series of 1 minute webdriverwaits?  So try/catch and function-ize your call there and set it to 1 minute.  If timeout exception is caught, notify and re-run function.  Use a count int and ++ each time.  Once it reaches 10 let it fall through.  Not sure why you'd ever want a 10 minute wait though... file upload?

Comment: You don't actually want webdriver wait. You might want to either extend it, or do a custom wait. Depends on what you mean by "check it out".  I'd suggest a 1 minute wait, then a check for the element, which if it i fails, it "notifies you" and then continues to wait longer. But that feels ugly/wrong.